# axios.create' is undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I am implementing axios interceptor in tsx for react native expo. I am geting following error:

> TypeError: axios.create is not a function. (In 'axios
> .create()', 'axios.create' is undefined).

How can I solve this?

Version for axios: "axios": "^1.2.1",

```
import { _retrieveData } from "./AsyncStorage";
const configData = require('../config/config.json');
const axios = require('axios');

const userApi = axios.create();

userApi.defaults.timeout = 4000;


userApi.interceptors.request.use(async (config: any) => {
    const token = await _retrieveData('token');
    config.headers.common = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
    return config;
}, (error: any) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});


export default userApi;
```